# Why is the Repellant Stick exploding other creatures?

Tags: fallout-3

Playing Fallout 3 after finally getting around to buying it and I've gotten the repellant stick. Then I go to do the Robco mission, which is just filled with things to hit the with a stick, and every single radroach I've smacked has, without fail, exploded. I know I have the perk which causes things to *occasionally* explode but from what I know it shouldn't be this consistent. I checked the wiki to make sure it was the stick, and it wasn't just mole rats that explode, but the wiki insists it really is *just* mole rats that explode when hit with the Repellant Stick. Is my game being retarded or am I just getting the weirdest luck with my explosion perk?

Comment: it's a Repellent Stick for mole rats, it wasn't supposed to cause their heads to explode in the first place. i would just pass it off as one of the "unforeseen side effects" Moria didn't account for (like the allergenic side effects which causes exploding mole rat heads)

Comment: @Memor-X It is explicitly only supposed to explode Mole Rats according to the game.

Answer (score 3):

Radroaches are just fragile in general.  It may just be a coincidence.

Comment: Maybe but most of the time they just kinda flop and stay still after death. Not explode in a green gooey explosion.

Comment: Then it's probably just a bug on the game's end.  You didn't think you'd be able to play Fallout 3 without bugs, did you?

Comment: @Selonianth - What level are you? I find Radroaches explode with pretty much any weapon + the *'Bloody Mess'* perk over about level 15